# pdfsharp кириллица

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

Есть такой код

```
// Создаем новый PDF документ
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// Создаем пустую страницу
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// Получаем объект XGraphics для "рисования" элементов на странице
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// картинка
gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile("путь до картинки\\1.jpg"), 110, 10);

// Специальная опция для шрифта. Это чтобы русский текст нормально отображался
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

document.Info.Author = "автор";
document.Info.Subject = "тема";
document.Info.Title = "заголовок";
document.Info.Keywords = "ключи";

// Создаем шрифта
XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 40, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
// Рисуем текст. Да да) вы не ослышались. Рисуем текст в указанных координатах
gfx.DrawString("Здесь был водяной знак", font, XBrushes.Black,
new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
XStringFormat.Center);
string filename = "Test.pdf";
// Сохраняем файл под названием Test.pdf
document.Save(filename);
// ... и запускам сразу в программе просмотра pdf файлов
Process.Start(filename);
```

но после генерации в полях тайтл, автор и т.д появляются такие символы

```
703>;>2>: 02B>@  B5<0
```

пример на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен если кто то подскажет как исправить.

Comment: знакомая картина. Где-то я находил хак с перекодированием для записи в метаданные файла.

Comment: я вот нашел это http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9523#p9523 но не знаю как присобачить к данному коду

Comment: Вы нашли именно то. что нужно. Просто добавьте класс-хелпер со статическим методом и получайте нужные для записи строки с его помощью. Разберетесь или все-таки показать полностью?

Comment: если не трудно то покажите

Answer (score 1):

У PDFSharp есть проблема с кодировкой при записи метаданных PDF-документа. На официальном форуме PDFSharp было предложено временное [решение](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9523#p9523), но видимо эту ошибку до сих пор не починили. Решение проверено лично, действительно работает.

Небольшой пример по использованию:

1.
Создаем класс-хелпер со специальным методом, для перекодирования строки нужным образом.

```
public static class PdfHelper
{
    public static string EncodingHack(string str)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(str);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append((char)254);
        sb.Append((char)255);
        for(int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            sb.Append((char)bytes[i]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

2.
При записи значений в метаданные, применяем метод преобразования.

```
document.Info.Author = PdfHelper.EncodingHack("автор");
document.Info.Subject = PdfHelper.EncodingHack("тема");
document.Info.Title = PdfHelper.EncodingHack("заголовок");
document.Info.Keywords = PdfHelper.EncodingHack("ключи");
```

В принципе, если запись метаданных выполняется в одном месте приложения, можно оформить код преобразования в виде локальной функции или приватного метода класса, в котором PDF создается, это не имеет большого значения. Я отдаю предпочтение именно статическому классу, т.к. позже, в нем можно разместить и другие часто используемые последовательности действий, например определение шрифтов, абзацев, таблиц и прочие полезности, которые можно параметризовать и лень каждый раз писать полностью.

Comment: я не очень понимаю в коде

Comment: так нужно сделать?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2zB9Qn0A

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Добавьте в проект отдельный класс, а в коде создания документа уже вызывайте

Comment: я совсем нуб в c#... не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: В чем работаете? VS? Тогда правый тык в проект в обозревателе решений=>добавить...=>класс.  Подозреваю что спрашивать какая версия C# используется нет смысла?

Comment: @Михаил https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b142f8e7(v=vs.140).aspx и https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt280280.aspx

Comment: к сожалению так и не разобрался...

Comment: @Михаил https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=he8tUpdGEbM&feature=youtu.be&t=83 Честно говоря больше не знаю чем помочь. В рамки ответа на заданный вопрос расширенная лекция про создание классов и основы языка ни как не лезет.  И вы так и не ответили в чем вы этот код пишете или правите. Без информации об окружении это разговор немого с глухим.