# Неправильно отображение ссылок в Pdfsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Есть код который добавляет текст с ссылкой на страницу. Латиница отображается хорошо, но вот с кириллицей проблемы.

```
var pdfrect = new PdfRectangle(rect);
page.AddWebLink(pdfrect,"http://www.ya.ru");
XFont fontNormal = new XFont("Calibri", 10, XFontStyle.Underline);
gfx.DrawString("ывыфвфы", fontNormal, XBrushes.Black, xrect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

Я пробовал использовать хак, предложенный тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759323/264107  но увы, с ним текст все равно нечитабельный

Comment: а приведите больше кода, у меня лично кириллица показывается верно, зато ссылка не работает)

Comment: В том решении хак исключительно для метаданных, в остальном при правильно настроенных шрифтах с национальными алфавитами проблем не замечал. Посмотрите в тексте вопроса по ссылке, там есть дополнительная настройка опций шрифта для поддержки юникода. В вашем фрагменте я этой опции не вижу.